# Search Dialog with search options

Tags: android

I would like to add a Search Dialog to my application and provide options like case insensitive search. So basically I would like to have several checkboxes in addition to the search edit text. 
Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Note that I don't want to use the search widget for compatibility reasons.

Comment: What about some code for a start? What have you done?

Comment: I have a simple searchable element like<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
    android:searchMode="showSearchLabelAsBadge"
 />